# number of primes of the form |$n^2 - 6n + 5$|?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

How can I find the number of primes of the form $|n^2 - 6n + 5|$ where $n$ is an integer? Through trial and error, I have found $n = 6$ (this one is obvious), and $2$. Are there any more, and what is a smarter way to solve this question?

Comment: I think $|(n-1)(n-5)|$ is prime if either $|n-1| = 1$ or $|n-5| = 1$.

Comment: I would say that the comment by Andre Nicolas is your answer. One of the factors must equal 1, and the other factor  must be a prime.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I did when I saw your question was compute about a dozen values for small $n$ and look them up in the OEIS, which gave me [A028347](http://oeis.org/A028347) and the formula $n^2 - 4$. Clearly for $n^2 - 4$ to be prime you need $n$ to be odd. Slightly less obvious, you need for $n$ to be a multiple of 3, because otherwise $n^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$. These conditions are necessary but not sufficient.

Digging a little further, we find that $n^2 - 4 = (n - 2)(n + 2)$: this is clearest when the formula gives you semiprimes with prime factors 4 apart, e.g., $19 \times 23$, $37 \times 41$, $43 \times 47$.

So you have found all the prime values already.

Comment: Do note that the equation $n^2 - 6n + 5$ has a different "offset" (to use OEIS parlance) from $n^2 - 4$. In fact, to properly make the latter exactly equivalent to the former you need to change it to $(n - 3)^2 - 4$. Very minor detail, though.

Comment: Yes, thank you for pointing that out.